# Как сделать текст с градиентом при помощи css3

Tags: css3, градиент

нужно сделать шрифт как тут приблизительно http://webbonews.ru/tekst-gradientom-v-javascript/

но без использования js, только один цсс, нашел пример: http://ajc.su/web-razrabotka/sss3-gradient-na-bukvax/ но он почемуто работает только в хроме. Как может когдато делал такие вещи???

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью картинки-градиента как [здесь](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/gradient-text.html) или используя тот пример, что вы привели, только для свойства gradient указать и другие префиксы ( webkit это как раз таки для Chrome, Safari и, я не уверен на 100% можно ли уже так говорить, для Opera). Посмотрите, например, [тут](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient), как сделать градиент кроссбраузерным.

Comment: это да, я тоже нашел как сделать под хром и сафари, а вот под оперу мазилу и САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ ie ничего нету, ну и по ссылкам там идет градиент не текста а фона